# Display a date in Google Sheets that increments by two weeks every other week

Tags: date, google-sheets

I would like a spreadsheet row to contain the date of today, but only on every other Thursday, changing at 9:30 am.
To give you an example:

Next thursday the 21.07.16 it shell contain "21.07.16".
Until in exactly 14 days on thursday the 4.08.16 it shell contain this date and than change to 4.08.16.

Also I would like this change to happen at 9:30 am.

I can not think of a way how to do this. Can you point me into a direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has to set a starting datetime somewhere in the past, such as July 7, 2016, at 9:30am.

Then find the difference between the current and the starting datetime. Truncate this difference down to a multiple of 14, and add this value to the starting datetime.

The datetimes are represented in Sheets numerically as the number of days since December 30, 1899. In this system, 2016-07-07 9:30 is about  `42558.4` So the formula would be

```
=42558.4 + 14*floor((now()-42558.4)/14)
```

The output should be formatted as a date.

A less cryptic version is

```
=value("2016-07-07 09:30") + 14*floor((now() - value("2016-07-07 09:30"))/14)
```

(`value` follows the local convention for parsing dates, but I hope the format I used will be understood universally.)

Comment: I tried this at it seams to be working perfectly fine! I can not exactly see until next thursday, but it gives me exactly todays date. To get this right: If I set the starting date one week later, I would have last weeks date and next week again right?

Comment: What if I wanted to send it always on the last thursday a month? Would that be possible somehow?

Comment: I switched to `ceiling` since `floor` fails to show dates correctly if the start date is less than 14 days away